# Writing Csv file to already existing table in SQL Server database using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I was trying to insert the CSV file to an already existing table in the SSMS database table. I have a data column in my data. But I keep getting this error when I try to insert data. Please tell me where am I doing it wrong because server connection and extracting data from the database are fine. Below is the code.

```py
with open("combine.csv", encoding="utf8") as f:
     csvreader = csv.reader(f)
     csvdata = []
     for row in csvreader:
         csvdata.append(row)
         print(csvdata)
for row in csvdata:
# Insert a row of data
    print(row)
    if len(row)>=8:
         data = [row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7]]
         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO BILLING_COPY (DATE, DEPARTMENT_NUMBER, DEPARTMENT_NAME, DIVISION_CODE, DIVISION_NAME, O_T_AMT, R_AMT, U_AMT ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", data)
```

Error:

> File "", line 7, in 
>   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO BILLING_COPY (DATE, DEPARTMENT_NUMBER, DEPARTMENT_NAME, DIVISION_CODE, DIVISION_NAME, O_T_AMT, R_AMT, U_AMT ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", data)
>
> DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 0):

File "", line 7, in
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO BILLING_COPY (DATE, DEPARTMENT_NUMBER, DEPARTMENT_NAME, DIVISION_CODE, DIVISION_NAME, O_T_AMT, R_AMT, U_AMT ) VALUES **(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**", data)

I think the data type you mentioned in VALUES(?,?,? etc) is not right valid data type, try using it as  %d or %s

Here is some example:
mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO Laptop (Id, Name, Price, Purchase_date) 
                           VALUES 
                           (10, 'ProductValues SP99', 6459, '2019-12-27') """

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)
connection.commit()
```

My two cents: Better to assign insert query to a variable just like data variable.

Comment: I'm getting syntax error when at " cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)" statement

Comment: Can you post the code you tried and the complete error message you received?